# Expand Button Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, icons, expand

[image: screenshot of the button and the html]

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# FIRST - GET THE WEBPAGE
url = "https://op.europa.eu/en/web/who-is-who/organization/-/organization/EP/EP"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

# SECOND - CLICK THE BUTTONS
test = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("op-icon op-icon-more tree-hitarea").click()
print(test)
```

Now my question is how to be able to use the .click() in selenium to extend this button/icon. Although I find some similar problems, it is never about an icon. I am at loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.op-icon.op-icon-more.tree-hitarea").click()
```

Multiple class names in css selector or seperated by a .

Answer (score 0):

to expand the button you will needed to use the xpath of element and than to click it.
Install the chrome addon XPath Helper from chrome and then after refresh click the addon and then shift + click on the element what you neded.
After that use driver.find_element_by_xpath().click()